# Dynamically create more than one instance of class and reference it

Tags: oop, class, object, dynamic

I want to dynamically create more than one instance of the BindingSource class to be public throughout my Form.

If I use Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(BindingSource)) it will only create one instance of this class.

How can I create multiple instances of this class and reference them uniquely.

The number of instances needed is not known at design time, so I cannot do

```
Dim o1 As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(BindingSource))
Dim o2 As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(BindingSource))
Dim o3 As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(BindingSource))
```

It's in vb.net

I hope I make sense...

Regards
Marius

Comment: What language is this? Try using better tags. Why do you want a public binding source?

Comment: The same as when you drag a BindingSource onto the form. I want to get the same result through code.

Comment: Controls added through the form designer generate the code. Binding Sources are units for binding to a source of data. Why not make the backing data "public" to what needs to consume it? And the other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your design doesn't make any sense. But, I'll answer your question, and you can ask a new question to puzzle out the flaws in your design.

Make a dynamic collection, such as `List<BindingSource>` that you can add to as needed.

Then, in a loop, you can instantiate as many `BindingSource` as you need, and add them to the `List<BindingSource>` as needed.